# How to interpret scope waveform of UART STM32

Tags: embedded

I have written the code shown below to generate a sequence of 0b10101000 in   115200 baudrate.

I have defined the code by the reference manual using the formula shown below.

I have defined it to be 8 bit with no parity bit.

115200HZ is 8.6us.

The problem is that I can't see my data in the scope waveform.  I have '1' at the beginning.

Where is it?

How can I see the baudrate from the waveform?

[image]
https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

[image]

```
#include "rcc_config.h"
void uart2config(void);
void uart2_sendchar(uint8_t );


void uart2config(void)
{
   RCC->APB1ENR|=RCC_APB1ENR_USART2EN;
   RCC->AHB1ENR|=RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;
   //why in EFR32 we haveoutput but in stm32 we have alternate function for GPIO
   //GPIO speed i did not use in EFR32 what is speed in GPIO
    GPIOA->MODER|=(1UL<<7);//pin A3
   GPIOA->MODER&=~(1UL<<6);//pin A3 
      GPIOA->MODER|=(1UL<<5);//pin A2
   GPIOA->MODER&=~(1UL<<4);//pin A2
    
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1UL<<7);//pin A3
   GPIOA->OSPEEDR&=~(1UL<<6);//pin A3   
      GPIOA->OSPEEDR|=(1UL<<5);//pin A2
   GPIOA->OSPEEDR&=~(1UL<<4);//pin A2
    
    //8.4.9 285 why we need 
    GPIOA->AFR[0]|=(7<<8);
    GPIOA->AFR[0]|=(7<<12);
    USART2->CR1|=(1<<13);
    USART2->CR1&=~(1UL<<12);
    USART2->BRR=(7<<0)|(24<<4);
    USART2->CR1|=(1<<2);
    USART2->CR1|=(1<<3);
    
}
//bitwise and
void uart2_sendchar(uint8_t c)
{
    USART2->DR=c;
    while(!(USART2->SR&(1<<6)));
}

int main(void)
{
    uart2config();
    uart2_sendchar(0xF);
    
  while(1)
  {
        
        uart2_sendchar(0b10101000);
        delay(10000);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's backwards on the scope, 00010101...

Comment: Async data is lsb first. The bit sequence on the scope is start (0) 00010101 stop(1). The baudrate is incorrect. Looks like it is off by a factor of 3. Confirm your fclk - this is determined by the clock setup code.

Comment: UART data is inverted. and it's sending 0xA8.  From right to left, that's what I see.

Comment: Looks to be 1/3rd of 115kbd

Answer (score 3):

UART sends least significant bit first.

The scope diagram matches exactly with the transmission of the 0xA8 or 0b10101000.

It includes a start bit of logic 0, the data bits as 00010101, and stop bit of logic 1 which continues as idle logic 1 between data frames.

Baud rate is measured by the scope, it is 41667 bits per second, so you have some clock or baud rate setting issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a complementing answer:

[image]

```
IDLE   S   0    0    0     1    0   1    0    1   S
```

UART is LSB first so this is 1010 1000 = 0xA8

Comment: Hello Lundin,How do see the bausrate in the waveform?
Thanks.

Comment: @ron398 You have 50us/square and the shortest pulse is ~25us (your scope measures it more actually than the human eye to exactly 24us). `f=1/t` -> `f=1/(24 * 10^-6)` -> `f=41.667 * 10^3 Hz`, so 41.67kHz. Now the scope could calculate this automatically too, but one needs to know this very basic formula in order to work with data communication and embedded programming.